# STM32 OSXMotionFX Library mismatch with X-CUBE-MEM1 drivers

Tags: embedded, driver, stm32

I recently installed the AC6 System Workbench in order
to work with the STM32 OSXMotionFX Library
and I'm experiencing some troubles related
to the sample application shipped with this library.

Let me know if there is a better place to post such question.

It seems that the sample project works with a different
version of the STM32 Cube expansion drivers for the
X-Nucleo-IKS01A1 expansion board of the base
STM32 Nucleo-F401RE board I have.

In particular the sample project links to driver files
that are missing, some of them seem with different names
compared to the existing ones, that's why I guess
the sample project is referring to an old version of the drivers.

Any one does know how to get the previous versions of the
STM32CubeExpansion_MEMS1_V1.4.0 software ?

I did already search the ST Microelectronics web site
but to no avail, the X-CUBE-MEM1 software 
is only shipped at version 2.0.0 
and it seems I need the previous version.

Thanks in advance for redirecting me to the correct site in case.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the sample application in the software package osxMotionFX v1.4.0. It is aligned to the new version of the X-CUBE-MEMS1 drivers (v2.0.0). Unfortunately osxMotionFX v1.3.0 is not compatible with the new version of the X-CUBE-MEMS1 drivers.

Comment: Just to clarify, I suggest to install osxMotionFX v1.4.0 and use it together with X-CUBE-MEMS1 v2.0.0.

Comment: Did they upgrade it yesterday ? otherwise I feel it will have the very same problem to be linked to the old cube-mems1 drivers... In fact, what I tried is exactly the 1.4.0 version of the library 10-December-2015 whose Main Changes (Update application code to the new X-CUBE-MEMS1 APIs) are not reflected on the sample application it is shipped with.

Answer (score 0):

You mean that osxMotionFX v1.4.0 does not work with X-CUBE-MEMS1 v2.0.0? It is very strange. I'm able to use them without any issue. So probably, you are using osxMotionFX v1.4.0 with an old version of X-CUBE-MEMS1 package. Try to uninstall your current osxMotionFX package, download again the X-CUBE-MEMS1 package v2.0.0 and reinstall the osxMotionFX v1.4.0 over the new X-CUBE-MEMS1 package v2.0.0. Let me know if it fixes your issue.

Comment: Probably you are using the library itself with x-cube, but I'm pretty sure I'm using both the latest osxMotionFX 1.4.0 and x-cube 2.0.0 and the sample application shipped with osxMotionFX 1.4.0 (not the library itself) does use the old (I guess) x-cube, as some of the headers, see for instance "x_nucleo_iks01a1_accelero.h"  "x_nucleo_iks01a1_gyro.h" have different names from the more recent "x_nucleo_iks01a1_imu_6axes.h" shipped with x-cube.

Answer (score 0):

I use sample application of osxMotionFX v1.4.0 with X-CUBE-MEMS1 v2.0.0. I'm sure that you are not using X-CUBE-MEMS1 v2.0.0 because "x_nucleo_iks01a1_accelero.h" and "x_nucleo_iks01a1_gyro.h" are only defined in X-CUBE-MEMS1 v2.0.0 and not in the previous version of the package. You can also cross-check it looking at the installation folder that you are using for osxMotionFX; if it is not "STM32CubeExpansion_MEMS1_V2.0.0", then you are using a previous version of X-CUBE-MEMS1. Please, try to download again X-CUBE-MEMS1 software package.